# Coin Change Algorithm - coding challenge

Tags: java

Recently I came across a coding problem where I have to find the least positive value which is not possible to make using the coins present in the coin denomination array(array values can be used only once).
suppose that

if the input is 3 5 7, the answer is 1

if the input is 1 2 4, the answer is 8

if the input is 1 3 4, the answer is 2

I have written a solution using recursion but it has a time complexity of \$O(n!)\$.
It is given that the size of the array cannot be greater than 25 and no individual value being greater than 100,000.

```
    public class Test {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            int coins = scan.nextByte(); // max 25
            int maxPossible = 0;
            Integer[] coinsDenominationarray = new Integer[coins];
            for (int i = 0; i < coins; i++) {
                coinsDenominationarray[i] = scan.nextInt(); // max 1,00,000
                maxPossible += coinsDenominationarray[i];
            }
            Arrays.sort(coinsDenominationarray);
        /* 
         * +1 because the coins will not be able to make 1 more than sum of all the coins. 
         * Using this value for the upper limit for the for-loop. 
         * In case the recursion is not able to find any value not possible to make
           using any combination of coins. This will be the final answer.
        */
            System.out.println(solve(maxPossible+1, coinsDenominationarray));
        }

        public static int solve(Integer maxNotPossible, Integer[] arr) {
            for (int num = 1; num < maxNotPossible; num++) {
                if (isPresent(num, arr)) {
                    continue;
                }
                if (!isPossible(num, 0, possibleDenominations(num, arr))) {
                    return num;
                }
            }
            return maxNotPossible;
        }

        public static boolean isPossible(int toMake, int sum, Integer[] arr) {
            if (toMake < sum) {
                return false;
            }
            for (int num : arr) {
                int currentSum = sum + num;
                if (currentSum == toMake) {
                    return true;
                } else if (currentSum > toMake) {
                    return false;
                } else if (isPossible(toMake, currentSum, removeAndReturn(num, arr))) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }

        public static Integer[] removeAndReturn(Integer num, Integer[] arr) {
            List<Integer> list = new LinkedList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(arr));
            list.remove(num);
            return list.toArray(new Integer[list.size()]);
        }

        public static Integer[] possibleDenominations(Integer maxNum, Integer[] arr) {
            List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int num : arr) {
                if (num >= maxNum) {
                    break;
                }
                list.add(num);
            }
            return list.toArray(new Integer[list.size()]);
        }

        public static boolean isPresent(int num, Integer[] arr) {
            List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(arr);
            return list.contains(num);
        }

    }
```

link to the original challenge:
https://www.techgig.com/challenge/IG_Graduate_Programme_2018

Unfortunately, this is not an open challenge.

Comment: @MartinR I'd say the answer for 1 2 4 is 8 (unless multiplication is also allowed). 7 is definitely still possible, so not the correct answer.

Comment: Please provide a link to the original challenge if possible. Is it by chance the same challenge as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3947867/1014587)?

Answer (score 3):

I'll start with a review of your existing code, and then make a suggestion
for a better algorithm.

The first thing to notice is that there are *many* conversions from arrays
to lists and back to arrays:

- In the `isPresent()` function, the array is converted to a list in order
  to check if it contains a given number. But the array is already sorted,
  so one can call `Arrays.binarySearch` instead, which is more also efficient.
- The `possibleDenominations` function “truncates” the given array by conversion
  to a list and back to an array.
  You could compute the last index to be included instead and then return
  a subarray with `Arrays.copyOfRange`. But I am not sure if this truncating
  is needed at all, since your solution algorithm already early returns if 
  the values become too large.
- In the `removeAndReturn` function, the array is converted to a list
  and back to an array in order to get a new array with the first element
  removed.

All these conversions can be avoided completely: Either

- keep the original array and pass *indices* (of the first and last
  entry to be considered) around, or
- store the values in an `(Array)List` right at the beginning, and use 
  `list.subList()` to pass *views* of a portion of the list around, without
  actually copying the elements.

The method

> ```
> public static boolean isPossible(int toMake, int sum, Integer[] arr) {
> ```

can be simplified by taking a single parameter `targetSum` instead of
`toMake` and `sum`:

```
public static boolean isPossible(int targetSum, Integer[] arr) {
    if (targetSum == 0) {
        return true;
    } else if (targetSum < 0) {
        return false;
    }
    for (int num : arr) {
        if (isPossible(targetSum - num, removeAndReturn(num, arr))) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Further remarks:

- “Test” is a non-descriptive name for a program. Why not name it after the
  challenge, for example `public class CoinChange`?
- Why do you call `nextByte()` if the result is assigned to an `int`?
- The variable name `coins` does not clearly indicate that this is the
  *number* of coins.
- `coinsDenominationarray` is an array, but there is no need to make the type
  part of the variable name, I would call it for example `coinDenominations` or
  `coinValues`.
- Most of the code is done in a separate function, which is good. I would put
  the calculation of `maxPossible` and the sorting into that function as well,
  so that I/O and the actual computation are separated completely.
- The parameter name `arr` in the `solve` function  is non-descriptive.
  Why not use the same name as in the main program?
- All methods (with the only exception of `main`) can be `private`.

Putting it all together, the program could look like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Collections;

public class CoinChange {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int numCoins = scan.nextInt();

        ArrayList<Integer> coinValues = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int i = 0; i < numCoins; i++) {
            coinValues.add(scan.nextInt());
        }
        int firstNotPossible = findFirstNotPossible(coinValues);
        System.out.println(firstNotPossible);
    }

    private static int findFirstNotPossible(List<Integer> coinValues) {
        Collections.sort(coinValues);

        // Compute sum of values plus one:
        int maxNotPossible = 1;
        for (int value : coinValues) {
            maxNotPossible += value;
        }

        for (int num = 1; num < maxNotPossible; num++) {
            if (!coinValues.contains(num) && !isSummable(num, coinValues)) {
                return num;
            }
        }
        return maxNotPossible;
    }

    // Check if `targetSum` is representable as a sum of numbers in `values`
    // (which is assumed to be a sorted list of positive numbers).
    private static boolean isSummable(int targetSum, List<Integer> values) {
        if (targetSum == 0) {
            return true;
        } else if (targetSum < 0) {
            return false;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < values.size(); i += 1) {
            if (isSummable(targetSum - values.get(i), values.subList(i + 1, values.size()))) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

#### A better algorithm

Your `isPossible()` function solves the ["Subset sum problem"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem)
with “brute force,” i.e. by (recursively) trying all possible combinations.

This problem can be efficiently solved with "dynamic programming", as described in
the Wikipedia article.

But *this* problem can be solved even simpler:

- A number \$ N \$  stores the lowest value which is not
  representable as sum of coin values considered so far, initially \$ N = 1 \$.
- For all values \$ v \$ in the (sorted) array of coin values:

  - If \$ v > N \$ then we are done, \$ N \$ is not representable.
  - Otherwise \$ N \$ is incremented by \$ v \$.

This requires only a single traversal of the array, and no additional storage:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class CoinChange {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int numCoins = scan.nextInt();

        int[] coinValues = new int[numCoins];
        for (int i = 0; i < numCoins; i++) {
            coinValues[i] = scan.nextInt();
        }
        int firstNotPossible = findFirstNotPossible(coinValues);
        System.out.println(firstNotPossible);
    }

    private static int findFirstNotPossible(int[] coinValues) {
        Arrays.sort(coinValues);

        int firstNotPossible = 1;
        for (Integer value : coinValues) {
            if (value > firstNotPossible) {
                break;
            }
            firstNotPossible += value; 
        }
        return firstNotPossible;
    }
}
```